# Broken line between line numbers and code in lstinputlisting with setstretch<1

Tags: listings, rules, line-spacing, setspace

If I use `\setspace{0.8}` to tighten up my listings* I get a broken line between the line numbers and the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont,  breakatwhitespace=false, breakindent=0.5em, breaklines=true, captionpos=b, extendedchars=false, frame=l, keepspaces=true} %this line intentionally long




%and some intentional blanks.
\lstset{  
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\selectfont,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  stepnumber=2,
  tabsize=2,
} 
\begin{document}
This is a singlespaced listing: 
\lstinputlisting[frame=leftline,firstline=1,lastline=9]{lstline.tex}

This is after \textbackslash setstretch\{0.8\}:
\setstretch{0.8}
\lstinputlisting[frame=leftline,firstline=1,lastline=9]{lstline.tex}
\end{document}
```

(save it as lstline.tex and it's its own example)

[image: above code, rendered]

If the breaking was regular I'd just accept it as a dashed line and move on, but it's not (see the very long, multiply wrapping line 3 for example).

I've played around with a few things while stripping down to an MWE but nothing helped.

Note that these are multi-page listings, so a box round them looks odd, the rule is really only to separate the line numbers from the code.

**EDIT** I compile with pdflatex (I think I have to).

*(the line spacing looks pretty big in *Latin Modern Typewriter Light Condensed* which I normally use, but the issue isn't font-dependent)

Comment: The left bar is formed by adding rules as high as a strut, but, with your setting of the baselineskip, some characters are higher than a strut.

Comment: @egreg so I guess I just have to keep increasing the spacing until it looks OK, to hit the minimum spacing that will work?

Comment: Basically so, unless you're willing to change how the frame is drawn.

Comment: @Jubobs it looks to me like a small nonzero positive value works by overriding the \setstretch - the 2 rules in the above example render to the same length within 1mm.  A negative value is good though.

Comment: @Jubobs... bizarrely `lineskip=-.1\baselineskip` or even -0.15 works a treat, but at -0.18 the gaps reappear.  The leading is also pretty bad by this point so -0.1 looks like the best option - at least in cm tt, I could go a bit tighter in lmodern tt condensed I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left frame is drawn by pieces of rules as high as a strut, but with `\baselinestretch` set to 0.8 some characters are higher than a strut.

You could solve by changing the way the rules are computed, for instance with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont,  breakatwhitespace=false, breakindent=0.5em, breaklines=true, captionpos=b, extendedchars=false, frame=l, keepspaces=true} %this line intentionally long

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lst@frameInit}
  {\vrule\@width\lst@framerulewidth}
  {\smash{\vrule\@width\lst@framerulewidth\@height1.2\ht\strutbox\@depth1.2\dp\strutbox}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


%and some intentional blanks.
\lstset{  
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\selectfont,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  stepnumber=2,
  tabsize=2,
} 
\begin{document}
This is a singlespaced listing: 
\lstinputlisting[frame=leftline,firstline=1,lastline=9]{\jobname}

This is after \verb|\setstretch{0.8}|:
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\linespread{0.8}\selectfont}
\lstinputlisting[frame=leftline,firstline=1,lastline=9]{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However the leading is uneven. I don't like loading `setspace`, so I changed the setting to an equivalent one.

I think it's better to just reducing the leading at most so that the strut is still a bit higher than characters, say 0.9:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\selectfont,  breakatwhitespace=false, breakindent=0.5em, breaklines=true, captionpos=b, extendedchars=false, frame=l, keepspaces=true} %this line intentionally long



%and some intentional blanks.
\lstset{  
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\selectfont,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  stepnumber=2,
  tabsize=2,
} 
\begin{document}
This is a singlespaced listing: 
\lstinputlisting[frame=leftline,firstline=1,lastline=9]{\jobname}

This is after \verb|\setstretch{0.9}|:
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\linespread{0.9}\selectfont}
\lstinputlisting[frame=leftline,firstline=1,lastline=9]{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been playing with values and even at 0.9 a "g", a comma or a bracket above a bracket or a slash leads to a tiny notch if I zoom in, even though there's now quite a gap between the bottom of the descender and the top of the next line (in lmodern tt condensed) so your new method (or @Jubobs' small negative `lineskip` for some reason) does the trick.  I think 0.9 *and* your recalculated rule might be required - but maybe that's font-specific.

Comment: @ChrisH Of course this is font specific and it also depends on what characters are actually used. In any case, reducing the leading may produce uneven lines.