# Using matlab prettifier to put 100 lines of code per page

Tags: matlab, resize, matlab-prettifier

I need to put my code for a software I have written in my thesis appendix. There's about 4000 lines of code across multiple files, so I'd like to have 100 lines of code per page.

Using these settings, I get about 30 lines and the comments wrap which takes up extra space (even though in my matlab code I already wrapped comments).

```
%matlab stuff
\usepackage[framed, numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{listings, color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white}, 
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\fontsize{6}{5}\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\fontsize{6}{5},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2   
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
```

and in the appendix:

```
\lstinputlisting[style = Matlab-editor]{GINA_Analyser.m}
```

[image]

Using resizebox, I end up with the whole code attempting to fit on one page, like this.
This code is within the appendix section:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\lstinputlisting[style = Matlab-editor]{FileValidator.m}}
```

[image]

Is there something I can do?

Comment: Have you tried to further scale the fontsize down? This might prevent the code from wrapping.

Comment: Hi Tim. I have. For some reason, regardless of how I scale the code in the header section for lstdefinestyle, the font size doesn't actually change.

Comment: If you aren't obliged to print the code, you could attach it to the pdf using attachfile2 or embedall. This has the advantage of promoting reproducibility and saving trees.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for the suggestion. My supervisor has asked that I have it included in the thesis unfortunately! Saving trees is part of the reason I want to make the text as small as possible while keeping it legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Latin Modern TT Light Condensed](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/latinmodernmonolightcondensed/)  for my code listings - it's narrower than normal TT fonts for the same font size so you'll get more characters per line, and fewer lines wrapping.  I also [reduced the line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168725/28808) just a little using `setspace`, which gave me a bit of trouble (the link is to my question about that).

Unfortunately the biggest gain may be from manual effort: Reworking the line-wrapping in the comments, for example.  Your lines 1-9 actually take up 17 lines; they should go down to about 12 if you don't break each one twice.  You can also reduce the tab stops to perhaps 2 spaces, and remove the indent on block comments so more characters fit on the line.  Even adjusting whitespace in the code itself is an option if your individual lines tend to be long; your example shows generous use of space.

With a few lines wrapping on each page, I got to ~62 lines/page. [P.186 of my thesis (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvw115wjthio997/Thesis_Master_Final_2014-09-09-10-52.pdf?dl=0) is a good example.